# Php parsing array

Tags: php, json

hi i wanted to make my database table look a bit smoother and better looking by making it a json array and this is my code :

```
<?php
include 'conn.php';

$getpost="SELECT * FROM posts;";

$post=$conn->query($getpost);

$postarray= array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($post, MYSQL_ASSOC){

    $temp['id'] = $row['id'];
    $temp['postcont'] = $row['postcont'];
    $temp['writer'] = $row['writer'];
    $temp['posttime'] = $row['posttime'];

    array_push($postarray, $temp);

}

echo json_encode(array("posts"=>$postarray),JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

but i faced an error

**Notice: Use of undefined constant MYSQL_ASSOC - assumed 'MYSQL_ASSOC'  on line 10**

**Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given on line 10
{"posts":[]}**
and thanks for the help ^_^

Comment: Missing a parenthesis to close the while-condition

Comment: :o you are right thank but another error appeared     **Notice: Use of undefined constant MYSQL_ASSOC - assumed 'MYSQL_ASSOC' in /storage/ssd2/168/2173168/public_html/getposts.php on line 10

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given in /storage/ssd2/168/2173168/public_html/getposts.php on line 10
{"posts":[]}** @Qirel

Comment: it's `MYSQLI_ASSOC` - missing an `I` there

Comment: Thanks you saved my day :D @Jeff